# ip currently active error

Tags: php, ip

When someone tries to sign up to my website they keep getting this error code:

> ERROR IP currently active

My question is how can I fix this in my sign up folder this is the only IP text I have so i'm unsure I bought the site yesterday.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Include your code in the question. Remove the whole second section of your code starting from the second query.

Comment: Clearly there's already at least one record in the `users` table with that IP.  You either want to perform that check or you don't.  Which is it?

Comment: so what code is it you need so someone can help me then ? as that only deletes the message popup on failed signup not the actuall site

Comment: @RichardTaylor: The answer below addresses the code you posted.  If there is some other code that you want us to address, you would need to *include that code in the question*.  How can anybody here possibly know what code that is?

Comment: @RichardTaylor You need to hire a programmer to debug your code, or find some other website that will let you dump your entire codebase into it and have people fix it for you. That is not Stack Overflow. I'm sorry, but we can't tell you what code to post. You are expected to have enough knowledge as a programmer to be able to find and post the code that is responsible for your problem. If you can't identify the code, we can't help, this is the end of the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

> i just want to know what i need to get rid of so i can get rid of that where it says ip currently active

Well, this is where that message is displayed (well, where it originates anyway):

```
$msg = "IP is currently active.";
```

So if you want to remove that message then you want to remove that line of code.  Which in turn means you can remove the `if` block containing that line of code, since it would be empty.  And unless anything else is using the results of the database query which drove that `if` block, you can remove that as well.